# Xamarin: trigger page function on device button press

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, device

I have recently started learning Xamarin, coming from different javascript frameworks. In my application I want to trigger a certain event after a hard button press, like the backbutton, homebutton, volume button etc. in Android.
In particular, once the volume button up is pressed, I want to automatically focus a certain Input textbox. I know that I can customize the OnKeyDown method in MainActivity.cs like this:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    // doWhatYouNeed()
}
```

However I don't know how to execute the doWhatYouNeed() method in a certain Xamarin Forms page, like the home page of my application.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: which page?  Whichever page is currently being display, or another arbitrary page?

Comment: The current page displayed on screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnBackPress method in YourPage.xaml.cs, check [OnBackPress Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms)

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    // Do you code here
    base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    return true;
}
```

**For volume buttons you can use these:**

```cs
public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyUp(keyCode, e);
}

public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but OnBackPress triggers when I press the back button on my device, right? I need to make it work with the volume buttons or any other button.

Comment: I have update my answer, you use these methods.

Answer (score 0):

> In particular, once the volume button up is pressed, I want to automatically focus a certain Input textbox

You can use [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to get KeyCode in Xamarin.Forms.

Firstly, you need to subscribe to a message in ContentPage.OnAppearing, and unsubscribe from a message in ContentPage.OnDisappearing

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application, string>(this, "GlobalKeyUp", (sender, evt) =>
        {

            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Key up event", evt, "Ok");
            if (evt == "VolumeUp")
            {
               // txtname.Focus();
            }

        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Application, string>(this, "GlobalKeyUp");
    }
}
```

Then send keycode to ContentPage in Android project MainActivity.cs:

```
  public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "GlobalKeyUp", $"{keyCode}");
        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I needed!